# Dropzone spinner spins forever after adding file

Tags: dropzone.js

Here's a live example, if you upload any file to the dropzone it will just spin forever, tried on multiple browsers:

https://buildgrid.com/bom_supplier_view/ZzrmkDNnx3L0W4NRUYOqVEap4GQXj1bP

I thought turning off autoProcessQueue would fix. Just FYI the files are intended to not be uploaded to the server until the user clicks submit.

```
var bgDropzone = new dropzone("div#dropzone", {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
        url: "/bom_file_upload",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 10,
        acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,image/*",
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        maxfilesexceeded: (file) => { // For replacing the current file with another one that was just dropped/selected.
            bgDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            bgDropzone.addFile(file);
        },
        dictDefaultMessage: "<i class='fa fa-upload fa-4x'></i><br/><h3>Drag & Drop</h3> files anywhere or <span class='underline'>browse...</span>",
        success: (file, response) => {
            toastr.success(bgDropzone.options.params.toast_text, '', {
                onHidden: () => {
                    window.location.href = "/bom/" + bgDropzone.options.params.bom_id;
                }
            });
        },
        error: (file, errorMessage, xhr) => {
            if (xhr) {
                toastr.error('There was an error processing your request: ' + errorMessage, '');
            }
        },
        uploadProgress: (progress) => {
            bgDropzone.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
        }
    })
    .on('addedfile', (file) => {

        var bomName = file.name.toString().toLowerCase()
            .replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
            .replace(/[_-]/g, ' ')
            .replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, (a) => {
                return a.toUpperCase();
            });

        $('input[name=bom_name]').val(bomName);
        $('input[name=filename]').val(file.name.toString());
    });


// Removes error state styling from form fields and the Dropzone.

function removeErrorStyles() {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('div#dropzone').css('border', '3px dashed #0076be');
    $('div#notifications').hide();

}
```